# How to calculate the new field of view from an existent one?

Tags: focal-length, field-of-view

I have a photo having `H` x `W` (height x weight) pixels and I know, based on the EXIF, that it was shot at `F1` focal length.

How many pixels I must crop (or add) in order to see how it would be the photo if it would be shot at `F2` focal length?

All the other settings (camera, stage, POV etc.) will be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the “effective focal length” of a cropped photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/how-do-i-calculate-the-effective-focal-length-of-a-cropped-photo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple linear relationship, the number of pixels to crop depends on the ratio of the two focal lengths, i.e. if F1 is half the value of F2, then you need to chop the image in half. Or more formally:

```
new height = H * (F1/F2)
new width  = W * (F1/F2)
```